# Why is there an audience user count mismatch between firebase and google ads?

Tags: google-ads, firebase

I linked my google ads account to firebase in order to use firebase audience in google ads.
I can see 2 default audiences: **Purchasers** and **All users**. But for some reason in Google Ads' Audience Manager user numbers are much lower than they are in Firebase audience:

Google Ads says:
[image]
And Firebase says:
[image]

What is the reason for such mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of thing that can influence to different count. First of all, google ads can see audience with full data that system need, and it is much less, than firebase shows. Then maybe there is mismatch between users that have cookie from google ads and users from firebase